# CSS-animated buttons on webpage aren't running all animations (buttons added to page via Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this webpage visual upgrade project, and I'm having issues with getting my animated buttons to, well, animate fully. They will change colors when hovered over, but they should also include a slight movement of the button text and the appearance of an icon next to the text, inside the button.

I tested this concept on a standalone HTML document, since testing repeatedly on our test-server still takes a while between each build-load (that's another headache, thankfully outside my department!).

The working concept as a standalone HTML page looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.leftEnd {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid #780a29;
  border-bottom: 63px solid #780a29;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

/*Button 2 was intended to be for a dropdown. Not using currently, but may in future*/
.button, .button2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #780a29;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.button, .button2, span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: ' \00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button2 span:after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding-top: .2em;
}

.button:hover, .button2:hover {
  background-color: #490619;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button2:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.button2:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="leftEnd"></span>
    <button class="button"><span>Type 1</span></button>

    <button class="button"><span>Type 1</span></button>

    <button class="button"><span>Type 1</span></button>

</body>
</html>
```

For my project, I cannot touch the HTML source-code however, so I had to modify the CSS slightly, and use Javascript to add it to the page. The CSS looks like this:

```
/*
Toolbar site-navigation links
Future: Condense/simplify this section
*/
.toolbar-btn-grp .leftEndCap {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid #780a29;
  border-bottom: 63px solid #780a29;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  cursor: default;
}
/*tbButton 2 was intended to be for a dropdown. Not using currently, but may in future*/
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton, .toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #780a29;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton, .toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2, span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton span:after {
  content: ' \00bb';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2 span:after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding-top: .2em;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover, .toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:hover {
  background-color: #490619;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.toolbar-btn-grp {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

And the javascript I'm using to put this on the page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#productToolbar').append('<span class="leftEndCap"></span>');
        $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="goHome()" class="tbButton">Main Site</button>');
        $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="contact()" class="tbButton">Contact Us</button>');
        $('#productToolbar').addClass('toolbar-btn-grp');
        }
    );

    function goHome() {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.main-site.org/';
        }     

    function contact() {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.main-site.org/contact/';
        }       

</script>
```

Now, the fact that it's specifically the features that are followed by `span` in the CSS which aren't working on our site leads me to believe that this is the key to the issue. I know that `span` works at the sub-div level, so I'm wondering if maybe when the `toolbar-btn-grp` classes are added via the JS that when it parses  the CSS class, `span` elements are left out for some reason.

Comment: the span should be inside the button, no ?

Comment: You are not appending span inside the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your CSS like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="goHome()" class="tbButton">Main Site</button>');
  $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="contact()" class="tbButton">Contact Us</button>');
  $('#productToolbar').addClass('toolbar-btn-grp leftEndCap');
});

function goHome() {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.main-site.org/';
}

function contact() {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.main-site.org/contact/';
}
```

```css
/*
Toolbar site-navigation links
Future: Condense/simplify this section
*/

.leftEndCap {
  position:relative;
}
.leftEndCap:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-25px;
  top:0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid #780a29;
  border-bottom: 63px solid #780a29;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
}


/*tbButton 2 was intended to be for a dropdown. Not using currently, but may in future*/

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton,
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #780a29;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton,
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:after {
  content: ' \00bb';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding-top: .2em;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover,
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:hover {
  background-color: #490619;
}

.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover {
  padding-left: 5px
}


.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton:hover:after,
.toolbar-btn-grp .tbButton2:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: -20px
}

.toolbar-btn-grp {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="productToolbar" ></div>
```

Comment: That did work, thanks. I guess I just had a fundamental misunderstanding of what `span` was doing in my CSS. I _thought_ it was placing the elements after it at the end of the button content, but apparently removing `span` and putting `:after` directly onto the class had the same effect. I just can't wrap my head around why.

Comment: @EtherealBug i would simply say span is useless in this case :) so less code and less headaches ;)